# corsheaders.E013 error in django cors headers

Tags: django, django-cors-headers

I try to open port for using django backend as API at 'http://localhost:3000'

here is my implement

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = (
    'http://localhost:3000'
)
```

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    *
    'corsheaders',
]
```

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    *
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",# new
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware", # new
    *
]
```

but I keep getting the error message like this

```
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (corsheaders.E013) Origin '/' in CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS is missing scheme or netloc
        HINT: Add a scheme (e.g. https://) or netloc (e.g. example.com).
?: (corsheaders.E013) Origin '/' in CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS is missing scheme or netloc
        HINT: Add a scheme (e.g. https://) or netloc (e.g. example.com).
?: (corsheaders.E013) Origin '0' in CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS is missing scheme or netloc
        HINT: Add a scheme (e.g. https://) or netloc (e.g. example.com).
?: (corsheaders.E013) Origin '0' in CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS is missing scheme or netloc
        HINT: Add a scheme (e.g. https://) or netloc (e.g. example.com).
.
.
.
.
.
.

System check identified 21 issues (0 silenced).
```

**PS.**

python version 3.10.6

django version 4.0.6

django-cors-headers version 3.13.0

Answer (score 7):

I think you should use "[" instead of "("

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000'
]
```

I think that'll do the trick.

If you want Allow all origins you can try this:

```
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```